# How to write a custom device registration function for custom device such as RTC or ADC etc.?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I am beginner to embedded device driver writing. I am trying to write a custom device driver for my embedded device. as I am familiar with writing Char drivers, UIO, MISC frameworks. let's say I want to write my own kernel device driver for RTC (real-time clock)module.

Declare custom device struct

```
struct rtc685_device{
struct device dev;
struct module *owner;
int id 
const struct rtc685_class_ops *ops
.....
}
```

Declare RTC custom struct operations

```
struct rtc685_class_ops{
int (*open) (struct device*)
void(*release)(struct device*)
int(*get_time)(struct device *, struct rtc685_data*)
....
}
```

Register device with kernel

```
 struct rtc685_device *rtc685_device_register(const char *name,
struct device *dev, const struct rtc685_class_ops *ops,
struct module *owner)
```

my question is how to write source code for this function ? i can see some random code for this register function . but i  can't understand . please help me to understand the steps to create full custom device driver registration function. lastly, I am a hardware guy and don't understand much about kernel things. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Please, do not roll such a custom driver. For RTCS, there is an RTC subsystem that will handle all the kernel and userspace communication. It is located in drivers/rtc. For ADCs, there is also a subsystem, IIO, located in drivers/iio/adc.

They both provide driver specific structures that you need to fill out. For RTCs, this is [`struct rtc_device`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.1.9/source/include/linux/rtc.h#L102) and [`struct rtc_class_ops`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.1.9/source/include/linux/rtc.h#L75). `rtc_class_ops` contains all the callbacks that you may (or may not) implement to get your RTC working, such as `read_time`, `set_time`, `read_alarm` and `set_alarm`.
These callbacks will be called when necessary (e.g. when a userspace application reads the time) by the subsystem.

Once you've filled out both structures, you have to register your driver using the subsystem registration function, `rtc_register_device`.

You can have a look at the [rtc-pl030](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.1.9/source/drivers/rtc/rtc-pl030.c) driver which is very simple to follow.

Comment: what if i we add a custom framework such as misc or iio. is it worth doing or not ?

Comment: Do you have devices so specific they don't fit in any framework? Even if this is the case, you could still write a character driver or a misc device driver, unless you want to reuse your framework for multiple different drivers.